# How to use pytest fixtures with Unittest methods

Tags: python, pytest

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.Testcase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.something = True

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def MyTestMethod(self, frozentime):
        fn(self.something)  # self.something is NOT defined
```

If I use `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)` I end up with some strange behavior from PyTest.  Instead of calling my `setUp` method before the test method, PyTest skips the `setUp` and calls `MyTestMethod` as if it was a PyTest `MyTestFunction` which of course does not work very well.

How do I get `MyTestMethod` to use the `frozentime` fixture without ignoring the `setUp` method that should be called first.

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.Testcase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.something = True

    #@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def MyTestMethod(self, frozentime): # Fails on call, because it needs too many arguments.
        fn(self.something)
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because the autouse fixtures are executed before the `setUp`/`tearDown` methods:

> #### Note
>
> Due to architectural differences between the two frameworks, setup and teardown for `unittest`-based tests is performed during the `call` phase of testing instead of in `pytest`‘s standard `setup` and `teardown` stages. This can be important to understand in some situations, particularly when reasoning about errors. For example, if a `unittest`-based suite exhibits errors during setup, `pytest` will report no errors during its `setup` phase and will instead raise the error during `call`.

[Source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html)

There's nothing you can do to work around this behaviour. You can either move the fixture-relevant code out of `setUp`/`tearDown` methods, for example: if `self.flag` is used in class-scoped fixtures, you can replace

```python
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.flag = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.flag = False

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def myfixture(self):
        print(self.flag)
```

with

```python
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def prepare_flag(self):
        self.flag = True
        yield
        self.flag = False

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def myfixture(self, prepare_flag):
        print(self.flag)
```

Or you can move all the `setUp` relevant code from fixtures:

```python
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.flag = True

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def myfixture(self, somearg):
        fn(self.flag, somearg)
```

becomes

```python
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.flag = True
        fn(self.flag, self._somearg)

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def assign_stuff(self, somearg):
        self._somearg = somearg
```

Answer (score 0):

As @hoefling mentioned, the two lifecycles are incompatible... but that can be hacked around if you're not aiming for drop-in compatibility.

```
import pytest
from pytestqt.plugin import QtBot
from unittest import TestCase
from myproject import custom_widget

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def qtbot_adapter(qapp, request):
    """Adapt qtbot fixture for usefixtures and unittest.TestCase"""
    request.cls.qtbot = QtBot(request)

def with_updown(function):
    """Wrapper to bodge setUp/tearDown into fixtures+TestCase"""
    def test_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        __tracebackhide__ = True
        if callable(getattr(self, 'up', None)):
            self.up()
        try:
            function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            if callable(getattr(self, 'down', None)):
                self.down()
    test_wrapper.__doc__ = function.__doc__

    return test_wrapper

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("qtbot_adapter")
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def up(self):
        self.widget = custom_widget.CustomWidget()
        self.widget.show()

    @with_updown
    def test_some_property(self):
        with self.qtbot.waitSignal(self.widget.my_signal,
                                   timeout=300):
            self.widget.do_thing()
        self.assertEqual(self.widget.get_thing(), 'foo')
```